# wait for Http response in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using HTTP request in angular 2. I want when I get HTTP response then next process is called.

**Example:** In a **form** **select option** values are coming from **HTTP get Request**.I want to form page is loading until I get response for select options.

**get function**

```
getSelectOptionValue(): any {
      let area_list_url = '/select_option_list/';

      this.urlGet(area_list_url).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          let data = response.text() ? response.json() : [{}];
          if (data) {
            Constant.areaList = data;
          }
        }
      );
    }
    return JSON.stringify(Constant.areaList);
  }
```

**GET function**

```
 urlGet(url: string) {

    return this._http.get(Constant.hostUrl + url, {headers: GlobalUtils.head})
      .map((res)=> {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log(res);
          return res;
        } else if (res.status = 201) {
          return res;
        }
      }).catch((error)=> {
        console.log(error);

        if (error.status === 400) {
          return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
        } else if (error.status === 401) {
          return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
        } else if (error.status === 403) {
          return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
        } else if (error.status === 404) {
          return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
        } else if (error.status === 420) {
          return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
        } else {
          return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: just call the function / *next process* from `subscribe`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't make code wait for async calls to return.

What you can do is to chain async calls, so that when an async call returns, some of your code is executed.

If you use `map()` instead of `subscribe()` you can return the created `Observable` for the caller to subscribe. If you call `subscribe()` the return value will be a `Subscription` but that is usually not very useful for the caller:

```js
getSelectOptionValue(): any {
      let area_list_url = '/select_option_list/';

      return this.urlGet(area_list_url).map( /// <<<=== use `map` here
        (response) => {
          let data = response.text() ? response.json() : [{}];

          if (data) {
            Constant.areaList = data;
          }

          return JSON.stringify(Constant.areaList);
        }
      );
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
this.getSelectOptionValue().subscribe(data => {/* your code that works with received data here */ });
```

Comment: I exactly use map in **get function** and subscribe in getSelectOptionValue()

Comment: and your answer through me **error: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined**  when I again use map in getSelectOptionValue().

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention the `return` I added where I changed `subscribe` to `map`. If you add `return` there, it should work.