# Angular 4 : Wait the end of http request to initialize form

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I want to retrieve a list of objects "*listOfArticles*" from the back before to call
next methods which initialize form and use validators on this list. But in my case, the form is initialized before the end of http request (because of asynchronous method). How to fix it ?

**Method of managementArbo.service.ts** :

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getProducts(parametres :string) :Observable<any> {
    console.log("Dans getProducts avec "+parametres);
    let url :string = "http://#####"+parametres;
    let observable :Observable<any> = this.http.get(url).map((res:Response) => res.json());
    return observable;
 }
```

**ngOnInit() method of myForm.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getListBdd();
    this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      itemRows: this.fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
    })
}
```

**getListBdd() method of myForm.ts**

```
public getListBdd() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let subroute = "getRefNumber";
      this.managementArbo.getProducts(subroute)
        .subscribe(
          res => { this.listOfArticles = res; console.log('bdd:' + res); }

          ,
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('getProducts done'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Move that logic into the `subscribe` callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wait for Http response in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102924/wait-for-http-response-in-angular-2)

Comment: @user184994 Can you develop it a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all your form initialization code inside subscribe of `getListBdd()`

```
public getListBdd() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let subroute = "getRefNumber";
      this.managementArbo.getProducts(subroute)
        .subscribe(
          res => { 
           this.listOfArticles = res; console.log('bdd:' + res); 

           // create your form here;
           this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
                    itemRows: this.fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
            })
         },
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('getProducts done'));
    });
}
```